# Selected color of prompt/message in empty text box

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I want to create Text box with prompt when it is empty. I use [setMessage method](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html) and it's working fine. How can I change default color of prompt?

Comment: `prompt` is of what data type? Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the prompt, just add a `Listener` to the focus events.

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("StackOverflow");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH);
        text.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        text.setText("Enter something");
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, true));

        text.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                if("".equals(text.getText()))
                {
                    text.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                    text.setText("Enter something");
                }
            }
        });

        text.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {

                if("Enter something".equals(text.getText()))
                {
                    text.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
                    text.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setFocus();
        label.forceFocus();

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Unfocussed/empty:

[image]

Focussed/not empty:

[image]

As you can see, the "prompt" is now red.

Comment: I want to add prompt by:
text.setMessage("Enter something");
In your implementation:
1. If I try to read content of empty Text I will get "Enter something"
2. I don't want to clear field on FocusIn. Going with tab key by form will clear all fields.

Comment: @KrzyH I don't understand. The text you set with `setMessage()` will only be visible, when the text field is empty, doesn't it? Then I don't see the problem with clearing it. I changed the `FocusIn` so that it will only clear the field if it contains some text that is different from the prompt.

Comment: The text you set with setMessage() will only be visible, when the text field is empty.But I want to change default message/prompt text color.

Comment: @KrzyH Well, you can't change the text color of the prompt. This is why I provided an alternative.